# Free vector image previewer/viewer for Mac?

Tags: macos, vector-graphics

Is there a free vector image viewer/previewer for Mac?

I need to be able to view .svg, .eps and .ai files to help categorize/sort them for work, but don't have Adobe Illustrator on this computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view SVG graphics with any recent major browser. Also, Adobe offers an [SVG Viewer for OS X](http://www.adobe.com/svg/overview/whatsnew.html), but it has been [EOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-life_%28product%29) since 2009.

There's an [EPS plugin for Quick Look](http://www.eternalstorms.at/utilities/epsqlplg/), which would allow you to "peek" into EPS files.

I think the only real alternative to Adobe Illustrator is [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/download/), the popular free and open source vector graphics application. Its interface isn't that pretty though, because it's still using X11/[XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki).

Still, you should be able to open any vector graphics with it, even Illustrator files.

[image]